# IntelliJ can not recognize Java 8 annotations on ARCH LINUX

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, annotations

I recently went from dirty OS Windows 7 to best OS Arch Linux. After copying the stuff over, IntelliJ does not recognize some annotations:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnegative;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
```

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_92. On Windows I'm using 1.8.0.

On Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SKDs -> Classpath Windows has the following additional jars:
sunmscapi.jar
access-bridge-64.jar

Apart from that I couldn't find any additional information. How can I make the annotations work?

Comment: What is your Project Language Level in File -> Project Structure?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. It is 8: Lambda, annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those annotations are not part of JDK 8. They are available in a separate JAR, and you need to add this JAR as a library to your project in order for the annotations to be resolved.

You can download the JAR, for example, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305).